# how do I make beautiful flipping images?

Tags: c#, winforms

When I opened the game launcher, I noticed how the news was implemented there.
And I really liked this idea, so I decided to do it in my project, first of all I made a panel, stuffed a few images into it, and then actually made two buttons with which I plan to flip through the images. BUT how to do it smoothly? Here is where the problem is, I do not understand how to make a smooth flipping of
the image

[image: Pointed the mouse]

[image]

Comment: far too broad for SO.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann  I didn't understand

Comment: your question, as is, is too broad. it's unanswerable. stackoverflow is for *specific* coding questions. it is neither a "how to"-library, nor a code writing service. also: if you have any trouble with your code, _share it with us_ - otherwise we can not do anything to help you improve your _code_. please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I would store all images in a list and draw them on the panel via OnPaint event. For a slide effect just use a timer and decrease the x coordinate where the image is drawn.

Comment: @keco can you tell me how you would draw them?

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell how the images are sliding, flipping, stretching or whatever, but I think WinForms with GDI+ isn't the best choice. I think WPF would be better. I would also recommend using a suitable library for those kind of image manipulations.

However, if you want it very(!) simple you could use this class:

```
public class SlideAnimation
{
    public event EventHandler<AnimationEventArgs> AnimationFinished;

    private readonly Control Control;
    private readonly Timer Timer;
    private float fromXPosition;

    public SlideAnimation(Control ctrl)
    {
        Control = ctrl;
        Timer = new Timer();
        Timer.Interval = 10;
        Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        Control.Paint += Control_Paint;
    }

    public float Speed { get; set; }
    public Image From { get; set; }
    public Image To { get; set; }
    public AnimationDirection Direction { get; set; }

    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get
        {
            return Timer.Enabled;
        }
    }

    public void StartAnimation()
    {
        // maybe move those checks into the setter of the corresponding property
        if (this.From == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        if (this.To == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        if (this.Speed <= 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        fromXPosition = 0;
        Timer.Enabled = true;
    }

    protected void OnAnimationFinished(AnimationEventArgs e)
    {
        AnimationFinished?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // increase or decrease the position of the first image
        fromXPosition = fromXPosition + (this.Speed * this.Direction);
        Control.Invalidate();
        if (Math.Abs(fromXPosition) >= this.From.Width)
        {
            Timer.Enabled = false;
            OnAnimationFinished(new AnimationEventArgs(this.Direction));
        }
    }

    private void Control_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Timer.Enabled)
            return;

        // draw both images next to each other depending on the direction
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.From, new PointF(fromXPosition, 0));
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(this.To, new PointF(fromXPosition - (this.From.Width * this.Direction), 0));
    }
}

public enum AnimationDirection
{
    Forward = -1,
    Backward = 1
}

public class AnimationEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public AnimationEventArgs(AnimationDirection direction)
    {
        Direction = direction;
    }

    public AnimationDirection Direction { get; }
}
```

This class will only draw the images while the animation is active. Every other invalidation will not trigger the `Control_Paint` method.

Use following code for your Form:

```
public class Form1
{
    private List<Image> imgList = new List<Image>();
    private int currentIndex = 0;
    private SlideAnimation animation;

    public Slideshow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        imgList.Add(Image.FromFile("pic1.bmp"));
        imgList.Add(Image.FromFile("pic2.bmp"));
        imgList.Add(Image.FromFile("pic3.bmp"));
        imgList.Add(Image.FromFile("pic4.bmp"));
        imgList.Add(Image.FromFile("pic5.bmp"));
        animation = new SlideAnimation(this.Panel1);
        animation.Speed = 20;
        animation.AnimationFinished += AnimationFinished;
    }

    private void btnPrev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentIndex == 0)
            return;
        if (animation.IsRunning)
            return;
        animation.Direction = AnimationDirection.Backward;
        animation.From = imgList[currentIndex];
        animation.To = imgList[currentIndex - 1];
        animation.StartAnimation();
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentIndex == imgList.Count - 1)
            return;
        if (animation.IsRunning)
            return;
        animation.Direction = AnimationDirection.Forward;
        animation.From = imgList[currentIndex];
        animation.To = imgList[currentIndex + 1];
        animation.StartAnimation();
    }

    private void AnimationFinished(object sender, AnimationEventArgs e)
    {
        currentIndex = currentIndex - (1 * e.Direction);
    }

    private void Panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(imgList[currentIndex], 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Since there are a lot of drawing operations you may use a panel which supports DoubleBuffer.

```
public class DoubleBufferedPanel : Panel
{
    public DoubleBufferedPanel()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that this example is very simple and far from "fancy".